# Nilpotent matrices linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let be $\ A \in M_{nxn}$ be a nilpotent matrix. Prove that any $\ A^k \neq 0, k \in \mathbb N $ is not a linear combination of the matrices $\ A^{k-i}, i \in \{1,...,k-1\} $.

Comment: Any nilpotent matrix of "size" $n$ is such that $A^n$ is the null matrix. I don't understand what you're asking or saying.

Comment: Sorry, rephrased it. I meant $\ A^k \neq 0, k \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $m$ be minimal such that $A^m=0$. By assumption, $m>k$. Suppose
$$
  A^k=a_1A^1+\ldots+a_{k-1}A^{k-1}.
$$
Multiply by $A^{m-2}$ to conclude $a_1=0$. Similarly conclude $a_2=0$, etc. Derive a contradiction.